# Get test plan directory in non GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to get the directory of the test (.jmx file). I'm using this when running in GUI mode.

```
${__BeanShell(import org.apache.jmeter.gui.GuiPackage;GuiPackage.getInstance().getTestPlanFile();)}
```

This doesn't work when ran Jmeter is ran in non GUI mode. Is there any alternative to this?

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you're looking for [FileServer.getBaseDir()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html#getBaseDir--) function

---

Also be aware that [since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to switch to JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting. The main reason is that [Groovy is performing much better than Beanshell and others](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black). If you want to use the JMeter Function - migrate to [__groovv()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), the relevant syntax would be:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir(),)}
```